# Get new access_token without user accessing the application

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-apps

(Assuming that the user has granted my application the necessary permissions.) Is there a way to get a new access_token on or before the current long-lived token expires without user navigating to my application page, whether I use Canvas based application or non-Canvas based application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there no way to get this access_token without user (offline_access will be deprecated by December 5).
But here is way to get longer lived acccess_token (up to 60 days).
You can read about it info here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/